# HTML5 microphone save to file on server or process on server

Tags: html, audio, microphone

Is it possible to get the microphone input using HTML5 and save it on server as a file or process it on server? I can't seem to find the rigorous information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to do this. Have a look at this javascript library called  `Recorderjs` on [guithub](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

It allows you to record and export recording in wav format.

So What I would recommend is that when the recording is finished(like when the user presses the stop button).

Just use the `audioRecorder.exportWAV()` function and upload the file on to the server via AJAX.

Also check these links for  better understanding .

[AudioRecorder example](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html)

[HTML 5 Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: I tried those in Firefox - didn't work out. Is HTML5 and especially audio/webcam capture going to be applied (standartised) to main browsers? If I spend time learning it now, I would like to use it for many browsers and not just Chrome

Comment: Mozilla does supports `getUserMedia/Stream API` but with its own vendor prefix(moz) and probably the author of the examples have not used it or else it should have worked.
Check this link http://caniuse.com/stream

Comment: As far as my personal opinion I think the browsers which currently are not supporting the API will play catch-up too, so its worth giving a shot.